# OpenCV shows no video from Macbook webcam

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using the code from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html):

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("edges", frame);
        if(waitKey(200) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

and almost everything works as expected.

A window appears, my webcam light turns green, and then, no video.

I've simplified my code a bit, since I actually don't want the transforms in the example. Just want to see a video feed.

I've googled a bunch, read a few questions, and nothing seems to work. I tried tweaking the wait time, skipping the first frame, using `cap.read`, including `highgui`, making `highgui` feel particularly excluded, and profanity. So far, nothing's worked.

I used built opencv from source, and am running `opencv2.4.13.6`. Using CMake and make.

my CMake is:

```
set( OpenCV_DIR /Users/jason.nichols/opencv-2.4.13.6/build )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage motion.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Code looks fine, are you able to open the webcam from other applications manually. If yes make sure webcam id is 0. In Ubuntu, you can find webcam id  like https://askubuntu.com/a/848390/390209

Comment: I can open it in OpenCV in Python with ID 0. Was attempting to port a working prototype to C++ for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, closing my terminal and reopening it made this work.

I'm guessing it's the environment variable I'd added in my `.bash_profile` during opencv set up, but not 100% sure.

What's really the tell tale for this problem is there were no runtime errors, no cmake errors, and no compiler errors.

I know it's not a satisfying answer, but if you get to this state, try turning it off and turning it back on again.

Again, specifically, the code compiles, runs, turns on webcam light, but does not display any video or throw any exceptions. In this state, restarting the terminal solved my problem. Open to better answers if anyone knows why. This will almost certainly not work for any other problems.